# Debug Oracle Java Tutorial - local variable accessed from inner class; needs to be declared final

Tags: java

If I try to compile this code I get an error that reads "local variable phoneNumber1 is access from within inner class; needs to be declared final.

Quite simple how do I fix this so it doesn't have this compile error? I've read the technical spec for it, I've gone through the tutorial, but I'm still at a loss. I hope nobody was paid to write this thing.

```
public class LocalClassExample {

    static String regularExpression = "[^0-9]";

    public static void validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber1, String phoneNumber2) {

       int numberLength = 10;

       class PhoneNumber {

            String formattedPhoneNumber = null;

            PhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
                // numberLength = 7;
                String currentNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(
                  regularExpression, "");
                if (currentNumber.length() == numberLength)
                    formattedPhoneNumber = currentNumber;
                else
                    formattedPhoneNumber = null;
            }

            public String getNumber() {
                return formattedPhoneNumber;
            }

            public void printOriginalNumbers() {
                System.out.println("Original nubmers are " + phoneNumber1 +
                    " and " + phoneNumber2);
            }
        }

        PhoneNumber myNumber1 = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber1);
        PhoneNumber myNumber2 = new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber2);

        myNumber1.printOriginalNumbers();

        if (myNumber1.getNumber() == null)
            System.out.println("First number is invalid");
        else
            System.out.println("First number is " + myNumber1.getNumber());
        if (myNumber2.getNumber() == null)
            System.out.println("Second number is invalid");
        else
            System.out.println("Second number is " + myNumber2.getNumber());

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        validatePhoneNumber("123-456-7890", "456-7890");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is to just declare the variables final:

```
...
public static void validatePhoneNumber(final String phoneNumber1, final String phoneNumber2) {
   final int numberLength = 10;
   ...
}
...
```

Comment: Happy to be of help! If you found my answer to be useful, you can click the checkmark on the left of the answer to "accept" it so others know it was useful. See also the FAQ on [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Edit: Thanks for accepting!